# django 1.8 changelist view and queryset filter based on logged in user

Tags: python, django

I have migrated my app from django 1.6.5 to 1.8. All are working fine except for queryset in a model admin. Code snippets below for admin.py:

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['department','name']
    list_filter = ['department','name']
    form = CategoryForm

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}        
        self.list_display = ['department','name']
        self.list_filter = ['department','name']

        return super(CategoryAdmin, self).changelist_view(
            request, extra_context=extra_context)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(CategoryAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)
        if request.user.is_superuser is False:
            form.base_fields['department'].queryset = Department.objects.filter(
                name = request.user.customuser.department.name)
        return form

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        '''
        Superuser has all permissions.
        '''
        qs = super(CategoryAdmin).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            print 'hi super'
        else:
            print 'not superuser',request.user
            qs = qs.filter(
                department__in=Department.objects.filter(
                    name=request.user.customuser.department.name))
            print qs, 'qs'
        return qs
```

I get the following error for the queryset:

```
1.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'super' object has no attribute 'get_queryset'
```

How do I resolve this problem. I need detailed code for the get_queryset method. Have seen many posts on the same but unable to resolve. Please guide. Using django v.1.8 on python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided an instance to super

```
super(CategoryAdmin).get_queryset(request)
```

should be

```
super(CategoryAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
```

Comment: @user956424 - No worries, enjoy!